# Clean version of post malone -White iversion

Tags: lyrics, remix

I've been trying to find a clean[Radio Edit] of white iverson, I can't 
find it.

All the youtube videos that claim to be clean aren't available in my country (UK) or aren't at all

[White Iversion](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLsTskih7_I): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SLsTskih7_I

If there is a clean version on Google play store, I don't mind buying it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Play:

- [Explicit](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Post_Malone_White_Iverson?id=Bm4ljk3tivqklsxh2ap43yrhv2y)
- [Clean](https://play.google.com/store/music/album/Post_Malone_White_Iverson?id=Bg72fvkigaf72jmynd6yyhny2w4)

iTunes:

- [Explicit](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/white-iverson-single/id1028466085)
- [Clean](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/white-iverson-single/id1032908844)